# How to run dockerfile on chef-client

Tags: docker, chef-infra

I have a good stuff in working with docker manually. I want to implement docker using chef. As a beginner to chef ,I wrote a sample docker-file which will install httpd service on centos:7 .

My docker file is located at Cookbook>docker>default>Dockerfile

In my recipe i wrote a command to execute Dockerfile on chef-client. When i run(command `chef-client -r recipe[docker::testing]`) on client i'm getting an error.

I have two question

1. I'm i following the process or not , like placing the docker-file and writing recipe.
2. what actually recipe can do for dockerfile

Recipe: my recipe located in Cookbook>recipes>testing.rb

```
cookbook_file '/etc/Dockerfile' do
   source 'Dockerfile'
end

execute 'Dockerfile' do
  user "root"
  command 'docker build -t sample:latest .'
  action :run
end
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:6
MAINTAINER Kumar
RUN yum -y update
RUN YUM -y install httpd
```

error:

```
Recipe Compile Error
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound
--------------------------------
could not find recipe default for cookbook docker
```

Please help.

Comment: This question is hard to understand

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to follow you. The error that you cite stems probably from a line in your cookbook saying

```
include_recipe "docker"
```

or

```
include_recipe "docker::default"
```

The reason, why this fails is that your `docker` cookbook has no recipe called `default`.

Once that's fixed, I suggest that you open a new question focusing on the other problem(s).

Comment: It's not `include_recipe`, its the `-r` run list override :)

Comment: And I think the cookbook file is also in the wrong place, it should be `cookbooks/<name of cookbook>/files/Dockerfile`